# windows 10 Fall Creators Update - Missing power mode slider in the taskbar

Tags: windows-10, power-management, battery-life

After Windows 10 upgraded to Falls Creator update, a new power slider appeared in the taskbar (when clicking the battery icon).

After some time, the slider disappeared and never came back despite trying all various tips and tricks found on various forums (sfc /scannow, dism tool, resetting power plans to default, etc...)

How can I restore the power slider?

Comment: See this....https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-missing-battery-slider-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

The only trick that worked for me is to update windows 10 to version 1803 (Windows 10 April 2018 Update).